# Move one option value into another option

Tags: options

I have 2 existing options that I want to move into an existing 3rd option. What is the best way to go about this? Here's the scenario:

I have 2 options in existance:

```
get_option( 'license_key' )
get_option( 'license_key_status' )
```

I also have another option set that already exists with data already in it:

```
get_option( 'my_theme' )
```

The my_theme option contains multidimension arrays:

```
$options = get_option( 'my_theme' );
$value = $options['key']['value']
```

I want to take license_key and license_key_status, move them into these 2 values:

```
$license = $options['key']['license']['license']
$status = $options['key']['license']['status']
```

Then delete license_key and license_key_status

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include more context.

Comment: @s_ha_dum added context

Comment: I won't be able to write this for you right now but essentially you just query the DB for your option, build an array and save it.

Comment: yes, i wanted to know best practice